# Помогите. Нужно сделать доклад на тему "Крапива Садовая"

Tags: вопрос

Помогите найти хоть какую либо информацию о "Крапива садовая". Я не могу про нее вообще найти информацию.. Может у нее есть альтернативное название?:

Comment: https://floristics.info/ru/stati/sadovodstvo/4125-krapiva-svojstva-i-protivopokazaniya-vyrashchivanie-i-primenenie.html О посадке, выращивании, сборе и др.

Comment: Нужно именно О Садовой крапиве

Comment: Какое отношение садовая крапива имеет к проблеме языка?

Comment: @Илья Вот тут еще есть: https://ekosad-vsem.ru/polza-krapivy-dlya-organizma-ee-vidy-i-blyuda-iz-krapivy/. Может, подойдет?

Comment: Существует декоративное садовое растение, которое называют "крапивкой" за сходство формы листьев с крапивой обыкновенной: https://selo.guru/rastenievodstvo/dekorativnolistvennye/kustovidnye/koleus/uhod-kol.html возможно, что именно об этом растении требуется сделать доклад.